# Objectbox = Is it in memory or disk database?

Tags: flutter, objectbox

I am building chat app in flutter.

I found objectbox with dart. It is look good. previously I tried hive.

My question is. Objectbox is in memory database or disk database?.

Hive is in memory database when I open my app. its load all box data in memory. But I am searching for solution like disk storage. So I can load data on memory when I needed. How Objectbox works?

Answer (score 5):

ObjectBox is not an in-memory database and uses available RAM efficiently. You get in-memory performance for reads when enough RAM is available. If less RAM is available and you operate on large data sets, it uses the disk more often. This is done also very efficiently using B+ tree paging.

There are also [two FAQ entries](https://objectbox.io/faq/) on caching/RAM for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Hive flutter stored data locally

For chat application i think you may go with objectbox with sync feature

Because i think it wont work if you only stored data locally, except you are doing the sending and received manually